Git LFS Server Error when Uploading RTF File
I want to track a single .rtf file of 55 MB using this command:
git lfs track "folderA/folderB/file.rtf"

I've also tried adding in a --filename flag. After some time, the server errors out with HTTP 502 and Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 6.0 MB/s, done. Fatal error: Server error. Not really sure what this could be because of how little info I'm provided (the rest of the error is metadata about the github's server and my repository), so I'm open to trying different things.
My Git version is version 2.45.2.windows.1, and my storage capacity is 1 GB which I'm already occupying 0.27 GB of it.

I outputted the verbose logs to a file and found this error 11:12:31.741208 trace git-lfs: tq: refusing to retry "...", too many retries (8). Perhaps there is something wrong with the file? It is a few pages long with a couple elaborate images, so, although not ideal, I'm thinking it could be separated for a file per page to be manageable LFS objects.

The file may be too large for something, but not for git lfs in general. Because what would be the point of "Large File Storage" if had to make your files small?
